# Mongoose RefPath, running populate() with NestJS

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs, populate

I registered by Schema with mongoose using Dynamic ref.  I followed the documentation as seen here:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref

```
@Schema({ collection: 'quotations' })
export class QuotationEntity {
  
  @Prop({ 
    required: true,
    enum: {
      values: ['PersonalClientEntity', 'CommercialClientEntity'],
      message: 'Please supply a valid client type.  Allowed: \'PersonalClientEntity\' or \'CommercialClientEntity\'.'
    },
    type: String
  })
  clientType: String;

  @Prop({ type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, refPath: 'ClientType', required: true })
  clientRef: Types.ObjectId;
}
```

So I save an ObjectId under the `clientRef` field which needs to reference the `clientType` field.  So when I use the `populate()` method, it needs to either populate 'PersonalClientEntity' or 'CommercialClientEntity'.

So I run the following query:

```
await this._model.find({ companyRef: companyId }).populate('clientRef').exec();
```

This does not populate anything.  When I replace the `ref` inside my Schema and pass in the actual correct reference, like so:

```
@Prop({ type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'PersonalClientEntity', required: true })
  clientRef: Types.ObjectId;
```

then the `populate()` method works perfectly.  Am I doing something wrong within my Schema with the `refPath`, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after going away from the issue, and coming back, I saw my mistake.  The numb nut that I am, made a spelling error.

This is my refPath:

`refPath: 'ClientType'`

and this is my model:

`clientType: String;`

See the issue?  See the issue?
Yeah, So I wanted to kick myself.